# Select rows out of Pandas dataframe based on index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Here's an example dataframe. I want to be able to select some of the rows out of that dataframe, and resort the selected rows, but keep the structure of the dataframe intact.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Study': ['ACME-XXX-YYYY', 'ACME-XXX-YYYY', 'ACME-XXX-YYYY', 'ACME-XXX-YYYY'],
               'Treatment': ['Drug B', 'Drug A', 'Drug C', 'Drug D'],
               'Sex': ['F', 'M', 'F', 'F'],
               'Subject': ['001', '002', '003', '004']})

df = df.set_index(['Study', 'Treatment'])


df#.loc[('ACME-XXX-YYYY', 'Drug A', 'Drug B', 'Drug C')]
```

When I uncomment the commented part of the last line above, I get this exception:

IndexingError: Too many indexers

I can run this code, which create a new dataframe that's a subset of df:

```
df.loc['ACME-XXX-YYYY']
```

But that is not quite what I want, since the resulting dataframe no longer has the 'Study' index. I still want that index. I also want to select on the second index, 'Treatment'.

This gets me the rows I want, but I was hoping to do this select with the loc function rather that the query function:

```
df.query('Study == "ACME-XXX-YYYY" and Treatment in["Drug A", "Drug B"]')
```

The above code also does not sort the rows exactly right. I know I can use the sort_values function on the dataframe, like this:

```
df.query('Study == "ACME-XXX-YYYY" and Treatment in["Drug A", "Drug B"]').sort_values(['Treatment'])
```

That is OK, but I was still hoping to have the code look something like this, with a reference to the index and the desired sort of the rows (which actually may not be an alpha sort):

```
df.loc[{'Treatment': ['Drug B', 'Drug A']}] # Doesn't work, KeyError 'Treatment not in index' exception
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you sliced would require to have **4** levels. You need to encapsulate the second level items in a list.

Simply use:

```
df.loc[('ACME-XXX-YYYY', ['Drug A', 'Drug B', 'Drug C']), :]
```

Output:

```
                        Sex Subject
Study         Treatment            
ACME-XXX-YYYY Drug A      M     002
              Drug B      F     001
              Drug C      F     003
```

Comment: This is great, thanks.

I forgot that I had to specify the columns part with the :.

Also, suppose I did not want to specify the part for the first index. I've seens some code -- slice(None) -- to do that. It looks like that works for one value of that first index, but apparently does not work if there's more than one value?

df.loc[(slice(none), ['Drug A', 'Drug B', 'Drug C']), :]

Comment: It should work. If you have more complex criteria, then better use boolean indexing with several masks

Comment: It should be `None`, not `none` :)